# TokBox retrieve user connection data

Tags: opentok, tokbox, user-data

When generating a token for a user for a session, you can add `connection data` to the TokenOption part of it.
According to TokBox, it could be anything you want that identifies the user with a limitation of up to 1000 characters. 
i.e.

```
TokenOptions tokenOpts = new TokenOptions.Builder()
      .role(Role.MODERATOR)
      .data("userId=12312")
      .build())
```

My question is how can I access this data?
I found no API to retrieve information on users in the session. I understand that an event is sent to connected users about other users in the session, but it doesn't seem to contain the data I put there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You can access the connection data each time a [ConnectionEvent](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) is fired.

For example, when a connection is created, a `connectionCreated` event is fired which has information such as `connectionId`, `creationTime`, and `data`. The `data` property will have the meta data that you set when creating the token. The `Connection` event is structured like so:

```
connection = {
  connectionId: '',
  creationTime: '',
  data: '', // this is the value that you're looking for
};
```

You will also have access to the `data` property in [Stream](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Stream.html) events because stream events include a `connection` property.